# Cannot create folders on my Kali desktop

Tags: encryption, desktop, kali-linux, desktop-customization

I just formatted my laptop with Kali Linux and with a full encrypted disk; this is my first time with full encrypted disk.  I Face a problem: when I right-click on my desktop, I used to find 'New folder' to create a new folder, but now I don't.  Even when I add a hard drive or CD, I don't get that icon on the desktop.  I tried to drag a folder or file, but that didn't work.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FaY3E.png]

Comment: I see you accepted my answer.  I am curious though.  What did you end up doing?

Comment: Does Kali have a "live" version to "try before you b̶u̶y̶  install"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem isnt encryption, its that Kali uses the Gnome 3 Desktop Environment.  By default, Gnome 3 does not use the "Desktop" in the traditional manner that most operating systems use.  Personally, I think this change is very strange.  Also, you are not the first to complain about it.

It is possible to enable to enable desktop icons in Gnome 3.  There are several working methods that can by found by this [Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=gnome%203%20enable%20desktop%20icons&oq=gnome3%20enable%20desktop&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0l5.10582j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8).  However, all of them require downloading software and making configuration changes.

If you are not comfortable changing system settings, you might want to consider a different Desktop Environment, or even a different Linux distribution.  I always recommend [Linux Mint Cinnamon](https://linuxmint.com/).

Comment: The solution is in here https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/nautilus/issues/158#alternative-solution

Answer (score 0):

Problem fixed thanks to Keltari who made me understand the whole problem and to this https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/nautilus/issues/158#alternative-solution

1. Just install nemo sudo apt-get install nemo
2. Open a text editor and copy the following text into a new empty file:
   [Desktop Entry] Type=Application Name=Nemo Comment=Start Nemo desktop at log in Exec=nemo-desktop OnlyShowIn=GNOME; AutostartCondition=GSettings org.nemo.desktop show-desktop-icons X-GNOME-AutoRestart=true NoDisplay=true
3. Save the text file as ~/.config/autostart/nemo-autostart-with-gnome.desktop
4. Run this in terminal gsettings set org.nemo.desktop use-desktop-grid false 
   And that's it I hope I maybe will find some problems later.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OOgxi.png]